# Conversion of Java object, containing 2 or more maps, to JSON using jackson

Tags: java, json, maps, jackson, object-object-mapping

Given a class of the following format:

```
Class A
{
    Collection(Item) x= new ArrayList(Item)();
    Collection(Link) y= new ArrayList(Link)();
    .
    .
    //You can add data to the Item and Link classes     
}
```

where we have

```
Class Item { 
    int x;
    getX();
    setX();
}
```

and similarly

```
class Link {
    ..//get and set methods
}
```

If i create an instance: `A obj= new A();`

how would i serialize obj using ObjectMapper mapper? Would it still be the same? That is `mapper.writeValue(writer, obj);

I want the output format to be:

`{
"x": []
"y": []
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON serialization of collections usually have the collection name as a key present, so if you serialize `A`, the two collections should be serialized how you wish it to be.